# Consulta con modelo relacional de proyecto personal - JHipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

Arme el proyecto básico con jhipster 4, y hasta ahi todo bien, pero ahora quiero ir agregando tablas de mi modelo de una app que hice en otro proyecto, y no encuentro la forma de hacer que quede la tabla users debajo de Empresa, mi modelo tiene

```
Empresa 1 -> * Users
```

Usando el asistente por consola me ha dejado destrozada la entidad User, y ya lo vengo haciendo varias veces y no logro hacer quedar bien el modelo, tambien intente usar jdlstudio y nada:

```
entity Empresa{
    nombreEmpresa String,
    domicilio String,
    telefono String,
    email String
}

entity Cliente{
    nombre String,
    apellido String,
    celular String,
    telefono String,
    email String,
    domicilio String,
    colegio String
}
/**
  * Relacion Una empresa tiene uno o muchos usuarios
  */
relationship OneToMany {
    Empresa{user} to User{empresa},
    Empresa{cliente} to Cliente{empresa}
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola es un poco tarde la respuesta pero por si no lo pudiste hacer:

```
relationship ManyToOne {
    Empresa{
        user(Login)
    } to User
}
```

Saludos

Comment: GRacias, lo pruebo en la semana, el proyecto ya avanzo, y lo voy a intentar en otro.